# Change Color Highlighted TextInputLayout and Raise the Height of the Hint

Tags: android, android-studio, android-textinputlayout

I'm working with a TextInputLayout in Android Studios, and when I click on it to type in text, it's highlighted green and the hint is covering some of the text I type. Is it possible to change the color and raise the hint to see the typed text? Thank you!

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/lastNameTextInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="168dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/firstNameTextInputLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/firstNameTextInputLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/firstNameTextInputLayout">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/last_name" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the xml code?

Comment: Added it for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint and Text overlap with each other because of static height `android:layout_height="47dp"`

Change  height to wrap_content `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

There are some attributes for changing background color and hint color:

- For hint text color  `app:hintTextColor`
- For background color `app:boxBackgroundColor`
- For stroke color `app:boxStrokeColor`

Example Code:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/lastNameTextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="168dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/firstNameTextInputLayout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/firstNameTextInputLayout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/firstNameTextInputLayout"
            app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="1dp"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/black"
            app:hintTextColor="@color/black">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Last name"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

For more info regarding attributes of `TextInputLayout` check this [link](https://material.io/components/text-fields/android#using-text-fields)